# Header Bidding. How many DFP adslots do you need to include in Pre-bid when implementing on page?

Tags: prebid.js

Simple question related to header bidding form a newbie.

When adding pre-bid to a particular page, do you need to add specific DFP ad slots for that particular page or all DFP ad slots for the whole website?

I'm guessing each page obviously has different Adslots so Prebid would need to made uniquely for the individual adslots on a particular page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Prebid works alongside your current setup—you can use the same ad units (one, all, or setup adUnits just for Prebid)

Generally your prebid config will use div ids to specify what to bid on so it shouldn’t matter if you reuse an adunit multiple times. (You can also use the ad path name, but these should be unique if you do)

For your DFP setup, generally its best to have a placement and add all the adunits on the page to that placement. You’ll then target that placement and add the price key value `hb_pb=0.70` for example.

If prebid bids are returned from the prebid auction, then this order is then included in the DFP auction where it could win/lose